# How do I find all the possible events that work with EventHandler?

Tags: front-end, dynamic, undocumented

The `EventHandler` documentation, More Information section, lists 5 mouse events:

```
"MouseClicked" "MouseDown" "MouseDragged" "MouseMoved" "MouseUp"
```

There is at least one other mouse event that can be used that is not listed in this documentation: `"MouseEntered"`

How can I find out all the possible arguments that can be used as events for `EventHandler`?

**Edit**

Also in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6459/in-inputfield-how-to-prevent-shift-return-from-generating-a-new-cell/6466#6466) answer we learn of an undocumented option `HandleShiftReturn` which works as a "name" with `MenuCommand`. From the documentation:

{"MenuCommand","name"}  menu command with specified name chosen

How do we find out all the possible "names"?

**Edit #2 19th June**

I got a reply from tech support. They state that "MouseEntered" and "MouseExited" in the GUI Kit are different from the ones in `EventHandler` and the ones in `EventHandler` are not yet ready for public use hence not documented. I didn't get an answer to my request for a full list of events for `EventHandler` (that are public).

**Edit #3 30th June**

Contacted tech support again after [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7458/easy-button-or-hot-key-to-switch-between-working-and-slideshow-screen-enviro/7461#7461). Tech support advise that there is no (documented) way to use the shift, option, control, and function keys with `EventHandler`. Further they said there is no way to use key combinations with `EventHandler`. Still no closer to getting a complete list of events.

Comment: How did you find `"MouseEntered"`?

Comment: It was in the interactive balance sheet CDF example that Wolfram released.

Comment: There is also `"MouseExited"` (somewhere in `MathematicaNavigator.nb`)

Comment: Now you can also look at the autocomplete list when you write `CurrentValue["` and some starting letter

Answer (score 16):

I haven't looked deeper into this but have you tried all the events which you can find in the documentation of `GUIKit`?

Especially here: [GUIKit/ref/GUIInformation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/GUIKit/ref/GUIInformation.html)

The list at the bottom contains at least all events you have mentioned:

```
{"Action", "ActionPerformed", "Ancestor", "AncestorAdded", 
"AncestorMoved", "AncestorRemoved", "AncestorResized", 
"CaretPositionChanged", "Change", "Component", "ComponentAdded",
"ComponentHidden", "ComponentMoved", "ComponentRemoved",
"ComponentResized", "ComponentShown", "Container", "Focus",
"FocusGained", "FocusLost", "Hierarchy", "HierarchyBounds",
"HierarchyChanged", "InputMethod", "InputMethodTextChanged", "Item", 
"ItemStateChanged", "Key", "KeyPressed", "KeyReleased", "KeyTyped", 
"Mouse", "MouseClicked", "MouseDragged", "MouseEntered", 
"MouseExited", "MouseMotion", "MouseMoved", "MousePressed", 
"MouseReleased", "MouseWheel", "MouseWheelMoved", "PropertyChange", 
"StateChanged", "VetoableChange"}
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of this.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Any positive results while testing these?

Answer (score 9):

So I scraped the internal files for whatever I could and this is what I got:

```
{
 "DownArrowKeyDown",
 "EscapeKeyDown",
 "LeftArrowKeyDown",
 "MouseClicked",
 "MouseDown",
 "MouseDragged",
 "MouseEntered",
 "MouseExited",
 "MouseMoved",
 "MouseUp",
 "ReturnKeyDown",
 "RightArrowKeyDown",
 "UpArrowKeyDown",
 "WindowClose",
 EvaluationOrder,
 PassEventsDown,
 PassEventsUp,
 {"KeyDown", "  "},
 {"KeyDown", "1"},
 {"KeyDown", "2"},
 {"KeyDown", "3"},
 {"KeyDown", "4"},
 {"KeyDown", "5"},
 {"KeyDown", "6"},
 {"MenuCommand", "CellTagsEditDialog"},
 {"MenuCommand", "CellTagsFind"},
 {"MenuCommand", "Close"},
 {"MenuCommand", "EvaluateCells"},
 {"MenuCommand", "EvaluateNextCell"},
 {"MenuCommand", "FindNextMatch"},
 {"MenuCommand", "FindPreviousMatch"},
 {"MenuCommand", "HandleShiftReturn"},
 {"MenuCommand", "New"},
 {"MenuCommand", "Open"},
 {"MenuCommand", "ScrollNotebookEnd"},
 {"MenuCommand", "ScrollNotebookStart"},
 {"MenuCommand", "ScrollPageDown"},
 {"MenuCommand", "ScrollPageUp"},
 {"MenuCommand", "SimilarCellBelow"},
 {"MouseClicked", 1}
 }
```

There's nor really anything wild here. A lot of menu commands, but usually those can be guess from a `FrontEndToken` [name](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2572/what-is-the-complete-list-of-valid-front-end-tokens).

What is intriguing is that symbol `EvaluationOrder`. I do not know what it does, but I can tell you that it had the value `Before`. Here is the list of events it was paired with:

```
{
 "MouseDown" :> (CurrentValue[
     EvaluationNotebook[], {TaggingRules, "InputNotebook"}] = 
    InputNotebook[]; 
   SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowClickSelect -> True]),
 PassEventsDown -> True,
 PassEventsUp -> True,
 EvaluationOrder -> Before
 }
```

Presumably figuring out what file it came from shouldn't be too hard, but I will take a stab at that some other time. I omitted the file names when I scraped the data and I'd need to run another scrape to get them.

#### EDIT

Ran that scrape. That particular handler is on some `InputFields` in

```
FileNameJoin@{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", 
  "Palettes", "NetworkGraphTools.nb"}
```