# Easy button or hot key to switch between `Working` and `SlideShow` Screen Environments to avoid trip to menu

Tags: front-end

When I edit a slide show it easy to copy whole slides in `Working` Screen Environment but nice to preview slides in `SlideShow` Screen Environment.

[image]

*Mathematica* has convenient interactive buttons to go to Full Screen mode and change slides.

[image]

**Is it possible to set up an easy button or hot key to switch between `Working` and `SlideShow` Screen Environments to avoid trips to menu? Maybe using `DockedCells` ? Any similar ideas ?**

Comment: Slideshow has its own `DockedCell` so while you could do as you suggested it would require you to create your own stylesheet that adds the switching buttons to your docked cell and preserves the existing slideshow `DockedCell`.

Comment: @Vitaliy Kaurov, How do you get the broken egdes shown in your post?I'm fond of that.

Comment: @yulinlinyu http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4148

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov, thank you very much.

Comment: Dear Vitaliy Kaurov, Could you tell me which photo tool did you use to generate [this picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xo8ZD.png) THX  a lot:)

Comment: @ShutaoTANG [HERE](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4148) and [HERE](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/771)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `NotebookEventActions`

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 NotebookEventActions :> {{"KeyDown", "s"} :> SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
     ScreenStyleEnvironment -> "SlideShow"], {"KeyDown", "w"} :> 
    SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], ScreenStyleEnvironment -> "Working"]}]
```

This is rudimentary so you can play around and choose your keys etc. but it seems to do what you want (it worked ok for me with 8.0.4 on OS X 10.6.8).

Note that `NotebookEventActions` can be set globally in the options inspector so you can paste:

```
{{"KeyDown", "s"} :> SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
         ScreenStyleEnvironment -> "SlideShow"], {"KeyDown", "w"} :> 
        SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], ScreenStyleEnvironment -> "Working"]}
```

into the options inspector. I just tried this and it works fine -- hopefully there are no unintended consequences so use at your own risk. :)

**Edit**

When I wrote this answer I chose "s" and "w" keys for "slideshow" and "working" just for example. Clearly it is not practical to tie up the "s" and "w" keys at the notebook level. However the next day I tried to make these event keys function keys and couldn't get it to work so contacted WRI tech support. They advise that there is **no** (documented) way to use the shift, option, control, and function keys with `EventHandler`. Further they said there is no way to use key combinations with `EventHandler`.

So therefore the stylesheet method that I posted the other day looks like the best way to (practically) achieve what you want.

Comment: This is better than my failed attempt even if it had worked.  I was so locked into thinking about menu items I forgot to consider what was really going on. +1 !

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Not sure how practical it is to tie up keys but seems to be what he is after(?)

Comment: +1 @MikeHoneychurch Nice. Little impracticality - cannot type w and s - perhaps just fixed with using up F7, F8 keys instead.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov I just chose "s" and "w" for stylesheet and working by way of example. You can obviously choose whatever keys you prefer.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov please see edit re: function keys.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Thanks for the update Mike, very useful.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov did you try out the stylesheet method?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch As of version 11.1 (Windows) this works: `CurrentValue[InputNotebook[], 
  NotebookEventActions] =    {"EscapeKeyDown" :> 
   If[CurrentValue["ModifierKeys"] === {"Shift"}, 
    CurrentValue[SelectedNotebook[], ScreenStyleEnvironment] = 
     If[CurrentValue[SelectedNotebook[], ScreenStyleEnvironment] === 
       "SlideShow",
      "Working", "SlideShow"]]}`. However, one has to first hit the Shift key and then the Escape key.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a docked cell solution that can be added to a stylesheet:

Firstly make the docked cell grid. I'm using `PaneSelector` rather than `If` to choose how to layout the docked cell. An alternative is to create two separate docked cells, one for working and one for slideshow. This seems easier.

```
grid = DynamicModule[{slideshow = False},

  PaneSelector[{

    True -> Grid[{
       {Button[Graphics[{GrayLevel[0.3], Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 30],
         (FEPrivate`NotebookToggleFullScreen[]; {}),
         Appearance -> None],

        Style[Row[{

           Button["\[FirstPage]", 
            FrontEndTokenExecute[ButtonNotebook[], "ScrollPageFirst"],
             Appearance -> "Palette"], 
           Button["\[LeftPointer]", 
            FrontEndTokenExecute[ButtonNotebook[], 
             "ScrollPagePrevious"], Appearance -> "Palette"],

           Button["\[RightPointer]", 
            FrontEndTokenExecute[ButtonNotebook[], "ScrollPageNext"], 
            Appearance -> "Palette"], 
           Button["\[LastPage]", 
            FrontEndTokenExecute[ButtonNotebook[], "ScrollPageLast"], 
            Appearance -> "Palette"]}],
         DefaultOptions -> {
           Button -> {
             BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 25, GrayLevel[0.3]},
             FrameMargins -> 0,
             ImageMargins -> 0,
             ImageSize -> 20}
           }
         ],

        DynamicModule[{cells = {}, tagFind = False},

         EventHandler[
          Dynamic[
           PopupMenu[Dynamic[0, With[{nb = ButtonNotebook[]},

               SelectionMove[nb, Before, Notebook, 
                AutoScroll -> False];
               If[tagFind,

                Do[NotebookFind[nb, "SlideShowHeader", Next, CellTags,
                   AutoScroll -> False], {#}], 
                Do[NotebookFind[nb, "SlideShowNavigationBar", Next, 
                  CellStyle, AutoScroll -> False], {#}]
                ];
               SelectionMove[nb, After, Cell, AutoScroll -> False];

               NotebookWrite[nb, 
                Cell["", Deletable -> True, ShowCellBracket -> False],
                 All];
               NotebookDelete[nb];

               SelectionMove[nb, If[tagFind, Previous, Next], 
                Cell]] &
             ], cells,
            Style[Row[{

               Dynamic[
                CurrentValue[{"CounterValue", 
                  "SlideShowNavigationBar"}]], 

               Dynamic[
                FrontEndResource["SlideshowToolbarText", 
                 "SlideshowToolbarCounterText"]], 
               Dynamic[
                CurrentValue[{"MaxCounterValue", 
                  "SlideShowNavigationBar"}]]
               }], "ControlStyle"],
            Appearance -> None,
            ImageSize -> Automatic]
           ],
          {"MouseDown" :> Module[{cnt, nb = InputNotebook[]},
             cells = {};

             cnt = Apply[(NotebookFind[nb, #1, All, #2, 
                  AutoScroll -> False]; 
                 CurrentValue[
                  nb, {"CellCount", 
                   True}]) &, {{"SlideShowNavigationBar", 
                 CellStyle}, {"SlideShowHeader", CellTags}}, {1}];
             cnt = (If[tagFind = #1 == 0, #2, #1] &) @@ cnt;

             SelectionMove[nb, Before, Notebook, 
              AutoScroll -> False];

             If[tagFind, 
              cells = (#1 -> "Slide " <> ToString[#1] &) /@ 
                Range[cnt], 
              Do[NotebookFind[nb, "SlideShowNavigationBar", Next, 
                CellStyle, AutoScroll -> False]; 
               SelectionMove[nb, Next, Cell, AutoScroll -> False]; 

               AppendTo[cells, 
                NotebookRead[nb] /. 
                 s_Style :> 
                  With[{ss = 
                    Join[Take[s, 1], 
                    DeleteCases[Rest[s], _String | _[FontColor, _]]]},
                    ss /; True]], {cnt}]; 
              cells = 
               Replace[
                cells[[All, 1]], {BoxData[c_] :> c, 
                 TextData[c_] :> Row[If[ListQ[c], c, {c}]]}, 1]; 
              cells = Thread[Range[cnt] -> cells]]]},
          PassEventsDown -> True,
          EvaluationOrder -> Before,
          PassEventsUp -> True]
         ],
        EventHandler[
         Pane[
          Style[Dynamic@
            If[TrueQ[slideshow], "Switch to Working", 
             "Switch to Slideshow"], FontFamily -> "Arial", 14], {150,
            30}, Alignment -> {Center, Center}],
         {"MouseClicked" :> If[TrueQ[slideshow],

            SetOptions[InputNotebook[], 
             ScreenStyleEnvironment -> "Working"]; 
            slideshow = ! slideshow,

            SetOptions[InputNotebook[], 
             ScreenStyleEnvironment -> "SlideShow"]; 
            slideshow = ! slideshow]}]
        }},
      AutoDelete -> False,
      Alignment -> {{Left, Center, Right}, Center},
      ItemSize -> {Automatic, Fit, Automatic},
      Spacings -> 3],

    False -> Grid[{
       {Button[Graphics[{GrayLevel[0.3], Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 30],
         (FEPrivate`NotebookToggleFullScreen[]; {}),
         Appearance -> None],

        EventHandler[
         Pane[
          Style[Dynamic@
            If[TrueQ[slideshow], "Switch to Working", 
             "Switch to Slideshow"], FontFamily -> "Arial", 14], {150,
            30}, Alignment -> {Center, Center}],
         {"MouseClicked" :> If[TrueQ[slideshow],

            SetOptions[InputNotebook[], 
             ScreenStyleEnvironment -> "Working"]; 
            slideshow = ! slideshow,

            SetOptions[InputNotebook[], 
             ScreenStyleEnvironment -> "SlideShow"]; 
            slideshow = ! slideshow]}]
        }},
      AutoDelete -> False,
      Alignment -> {{Left, Center, Right}, Center},
      ItemSize -> {Automatic, Fit, Automatic},
      Spacings -> 3]
    },
   Dynamic[slideshow]]
  ]
```

To add this as a docked cell:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], DockedCells -> {First[ToBoxes[
     TextCell[grid, Background -> GrayLevel[0.8], CellMargins -> 0]
     ]]}]
```

To remove it:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], DockedCells -> {}]
```

Notes:

1. This has been cobbled together after studying how other slideshow docked cells work. Note the red `EvalutionOrder` option to `EventHandler`.
2. This places the option (button, i.e. the disk on the left)) to go full screen from the working environment.
3. You can switch between slideshow and working via the docked cell by clicking on "Switch to Working" and "Switch to Slideshow".

To make the stylesheet:

```
CreateDocument@Notebook[{
   Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]],
   Cell[StyleData["Notebook"],
    DockedCells -> {First[ToBoxes[
        TextCell[grid, Background -> GrayLevel[0.8], 
         CellMargins -> 0]
        ]]}]}, StyleDefinitions -> "PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"]
```

From there give it a name and install it.

Comment: Mike, thanks for this work, I really like the idea. Your button DockedCell completely removes slide show's default DockedCell - that's not suppose to happen right?

Comment: Yes I have deliberately removed the default docked cell. I wanted one docked cell for both environments. You don't need the slideshow forward and back, first & last controls for working environment. I'll leave it up to you to make two different docked calls. To keep the existing one for slideshow you will need to overlay it with the switching button and make that layer active.

Answer (score 4):

You could edit the `MenuSetup.tr` file in the same manner as [`KeyEventTranslations.tr`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/880/121) to include shortcut keys for each mode.

---

At present I cannot see a way to make this actually work.  I am leaving the answer here for a while in case someone else can, and because I am curious to know what can be done with the `"MenuListScreenStyleEnvironments"` token.

Comment: +1 This is nice idea, thank you. I'd like to see also if someone will come up with button idea.

Comment: @Vitaliy wait!  I cannot find the menu items in `MenuSetup.tr` only a cryptic:  `MenuItem["Styles", "MenuListScreenStyleEnvironments", MenuAnchor->True]`  **This method may not work.**

Comment: Yes, it'd be good to check ;-) Maybe it'll still work out.

Comment: @Vitaliy do you have any idea how to use these "MenuList..." items?  There are a number of them in `MenuSetup.tr` and I don't know if it is possible to use these to drill down to find tokens for individual implicit sub-items.

Comment: Not sure yet... but I will think about it (no upper time limit though ;-) )

Comment: ``ActionMenu["ChangeEnvironment", RuleDelayed[#,  SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], ScreenStyleEnvironment -> #2]] & @@@ FE`Evaluate[ FEPrivate`GetPopupList["MenuListScreenStyleEnvironments"]]]``

Answer (score 4):

You can modify the stylesheet to add short cuts. For example:

```
SetOptions[
    EvaluationNotebook[],
    StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[{
        Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions->"Default.nb"]],
        Cell[StyleData[All, "Working"],
            MenuCommandKey -> "-"
        ],
        Cell[StyleData[All, "SlideShow"],
            MenuCommandKey -> "="
        ]
        },
        StyleDefinitions->"PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"
    ]
]
```

The above code adds the short cuts <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> to swtich to the Working screen environment and <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd> to switch to the SlideShow environment. You can see these short cuts in action in the following animation:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Carl, very useful ! +1 :-)

Answer (score 3):

For something really straightforward, could you not just use the built-in `Slide Show` palette? It has a View Environment button that allows you to select `Slide Show`, `Working`, `Presentation`, etc., from a drop-down list.

Of course this is not appropriate if you want your slide show view to be full-screen. But if you're toggling between slide show and working, it's likely this is something you might be doing during development of your notebook rather than during its presentation to an audience.