# Notebook's WindowSize interference with contents' Dynamic ImageSizes

Tags: front-end, dynamic, bugs, notebooks

**Bug introduced in 8 or earlier and persists through  11.3**

---

Consider the following MWE:

```
CreateDocument[
 DynamicModule[{x = {500, 500}},
  Framed[
        "test"
   , ImageSize -> Dynamic[Print[RandomReal[]]; x, TrackedSymbols :> {x}]
   ]
  ]]
```

The resulting notebook prints streams of numbers when you are changing it's window size. It is not expected since `x` is not connected to `"WindowSize"` option or `CurrentValue`.

If you nest more such `Frames` you can see ugly effect of notebook scrollbars position delay in reference to notebook frame.

---

Confirmed bug. **Can't** be fixed in 10.0.2 so we have to wait for next release. ($WolframNext)

Comment: This sort of stuff is infuriating. Creating efficient working layouts in Mathematica is enough to drive you crazy.

Comment: Related problem: [Resizing or moving Notebook window causes Manipulate to update its argument](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73489/5478)

Comment: Could it be possible that the resizing forced redrawing on the FrontEnd side, thus forced a evaluation of the Dynamic code regardless it's changed or not?

Comment: @Silvia That sounds like the explanation that I could live with but I it is not supposed to happen. At least this is what J. Fultz has said on WTC last autumn when I had asked him but that.

Comment: @Kuba Agree. MMA's dynamic system is too fragile..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also consider this an unacceptable bug. Nevertheless I wanted to share a workaround which I think avoids the problem but is unfortunately a lot of effort to add to more complicated cases:

```
CreateDocument[
    DynamicModule[{x={500,500},lastValue},
        Framed[
            Slider[Dynamic[x[[1]]],{400,600}],
            ImageSize->Dynamic[
                If[x=!=lastValue,lastValue=x;Print[RandomReal[]];x,x],
                TrackedSymbols:>{x}
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Note: my originial answer did actually answer a different question, the code shown here is an adapted version of the workaround provided by Kuba.

Comment: Yes ;) I did this because sometimes people don't go below first answer. Now everything what's important is scanned in a glimpse ;)