# Resizing or moving Notebook window causes Manipulate to update its argument

Tags: manipulate, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 10.3.0**

---

Check this example:

```
Manipulate[Grid[{{RandomReal[10]}, {Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]}}], {a, 1, 3}]
```

[image]

As you can see, moving or resizing the Notebook window causes Manipulate to update its argument.

Is this normal behavior of MMA?

Thanks

Comment: Mine doesn't update when moving the window, but does when resizing (Mac OS 10, Mma 10.0.2). Maybe Manipulate feels like it needs to update the graph, because if you remove this part, it no longer updates when resizing.

Comment: doesn't happen in Version 9.0.1.0 (Windows 8 x64).

Comment: My system is V 10.0.2 (windows 8.1 x64)

Comment: Confirmed on V10.0.2 Win7. I'd report it. It is certainly not expected (by me :)).

Comment: Probably not related but similar behaviour: [WindowSize interfere Dynamic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/61659/5478)

Comment: Using `TrackedSymbols -> a` or `SynchronousUpdating -> False` does not help.  (Windows 8.1 64x, V10.0.2.0)

Comment: Have you reported it?

Comment: @Kuba No but I will now. Thanks

Comment: You should tag it v10.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think I've found the guilty : this is **`PlotTheme`**

Since the problem seems to only occur when "plot" functions are involved, for example here :

```
Manipulate[Grid[{{RandomReal[10]}, {Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]}}], {a, 1, 3}]

Manipulate[Grid[{{RandomReal[10]}, {ListPlot[Range[10]]}}], {a, 1, 3}]

Manipulate[
 Grid[{{RandomReal[10]}, {ParametricPlot[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, Pi}]}}], {a, 1, 3}]
```

but not in other cases, in particular when other type of graphics are used, like here :

```
Manipulate[Grid[{{RandomReal[10]}, {RandomReal[10]}}], {a, 1, 3}]

Manipulate[Grid[{{RandomReal[10]}, {Graphics[Disk[]]}}], {a, 1, 3}]
```

and as there is no problem with version 9, and since `PlotTheme` was introduced in version 10, I just tested **`PlotTheme->None`**, and the problem disappears.

For example :

```
Manipulate[
 Grid[{{RandomReal[10]}, {Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotTheme -> None]}}], {a, 1, 3}]
```

Comment: yes that is the one. +1

Comment: very good finding, much appreciated...

Comment: Another bad boy is `PlotLegends` : `Manipulate[
 Grid[{{RandomReal[10]}, {Plot[{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
     PlotTheme -> None, PlotLegends -> Automatic]}}], {a, 1, 3}]` still triggers updating when moving the notebook (M10.2, Windows).@John Fultz: Can we please get a bug fix soon?

Answer (score 8):

This bug has been fixed in *Mathematica* v10.3.

[image: ScreenDemonstration]

Answer (score 6):

I consider this a bug. Although I have no solution, I can provide some further insights. The behavior seems to depend on the usage of any plotting command or commands that display something. The smallest example I could find is

```
Dynamic[{Plot[Null, {a, 0, 1}], AbsoluteTime[]}]
```

A simple static `Graphics` seems not enough, but if you use a `Graph` instead of the `Plot`, the behavior appears too. If you look at the cell expression, there seems nothing unusual there

```
Cell[BoxData[
 DynamicBox[ToBoxes[{
    Plot[Null, {$CellContext`a, 0, 1}], 
    AbsoluteTime[]}, StandardForm],
  ImageSizeCache->{404., {46., 51.}}]], "Output",
 CellChangeTimes->{3.6323472127299213`*^9}]
```

Therefore, the question is why the front end does trigger a re-evaluation of this `DynamicBox`.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**: Everyone reading this should be aware that SquareOne's answer contains the real reason and the best way to get rid of these unwanted updates. I'll leave my answer here as I think it shows useful techniques to avoid unwanted updates in similar cases but using `PlotTheme->None` is certainly the best solution to the OPs problem...

It probably could be argued that the version 10 behavior is OK as the window size might cause changes in any of the manipulates content, e.g. when using something like `ImageSize->Full` or `CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowSize]`. The updates when a window moves could then be explained by details of how WindowSizes and WindowMarging are internally handled which would also explain why that seems to be platform dependent. On the other hand it seems to be a confirmed bug and I certainly would consider this an inacceptable misbehavior when using an explicit `TrackedSymbols:>{a}` to either the `Manipulate` or an additional `Dynamic` wrapper for the `Plot`.

Apart from that I wanted to share a workaround which seems to avoid the problem but is quite some effort to implement in more complicated cases:

```
DynamicModule[{output, lastValue},
  Manipulate[
    DynamicWrapper[
      output,
      If[lastValue=!= a,
        lastValue = a;
        output = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
           PlotLabel -> {a, RandomReal[]}, 
           ImageSize -> {500, 500./GoldenRatio}
        ]
      ],
      TrackedSymbols :> {a}
    ],
    {a, 1, 3}
  ]
]
```

the following might make the workaround easier to apply to a larger amount of code:

```
SetAttributes[saveDynamic,HoldAll];
saveDynamic[expr_,TrackedSymbols:>{symbol_Symbol}]:=DynamicModule[{lastValue,output=""},
    Column[{
    DynamicWrapper[
        Dynamic[output,TrackedSymbols:>{output}],
        If[lastValue=!=symbol,
            lastValue=symbol;
            output=expr
        ],
        TrackedSymbols:>{symbol}
    ]
    }]
];
```

One could of course adopt this to accept more than one tracked symbol and only use that definition instead of a standard `Dynamic` for those versions which show the erronous behavior.

Comment: But for other issues like PlotLegends your solution is much more general and better. I.e., this: `DynamicModule[{output, lastValue}, 
 Manipulate[DynamicWrapper[output, If[lastValue =!= a, lastValue = a;
    output = 
     Column[{RandomReal[], 
       Plot[{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
        PlotLegends -> "Expressions", PlotLabel -> {a, RandomReal[]}, 
        ImageSize -> {500, 500./GoldenRatio}]}]], 
   TrackedSymbols :> {a}], {a, 1, 3}]]` works just fine!

Comment: thanks @RolfMertig , I was hoping it would be helpful and left it here because of that. Have you tried if these unexpected updatesx are still an issue with the latest versions? I'm afraid that this behaviour will stay as it is as a fix might make necessary changes at a very deep level for use cases which WRI might classify as "too exotic" for such a change...

Comment: @RolfMertig: just have seen your other comment which exactly answers my question...