# Possible bug with Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.1.0 and fixed in 10.2.0**

---

I am observing a potential bug not present in MMA 10.0.1.0 on Win 7 Ultimate, but observable on MMA 10.1 on Win 7 Enterprise. It seems to work with every `Manipulate` construct. A very simple example is presented below:

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[a x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}], {a, 1, 10}]
```

After evaluating this expression, move the slider somewhere towards the right, then click on the little `+` sign to expand the controls. The slider instantly jumps to the leftmost limit, resetting the setting.

Can anybody confirm such behavior and, maybe, confirm this as a bug?

PS In the case that the problem is not observed by other users, I will be back at work tomorrow European afternoon (where I have 10.1/Enterprise) to give more details.

**EDIT**
As correctly observed in the answer to the linked duplicate question, this is a bug of `Manipulator`, the default control in `Manipulate`, however it does not seem to be related to `PlotTheme` or plotting functions. In any case, other users report the bug to be fixed in 10.2, however the problem in 10.1 is more general than just when using `DialogInput` as in the linked question: it can be reproduced when starting with *any* manipulator with initially collapsed controls and then expanding them.

Comment: Confirmed. It's fixed in 10.2.0.

Comment: It wasn't like that on v9 :)

Comment: @ilian Do you also have Win7 enterprise? To everyone else: can anyone confirm this as 10.1-specific or system specific or whatever? As soon as this is localized, the best possible answer would be to post where and under which OS this happens. Also I'm suprprised, that this question didn't come up before :-)

Comment: @LLIAMnYP Not OS specific.

Comment: It was noticed by @halirutan in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21241799#21241799) and i also confirmed [that](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21387778#21387778)

Comment: @MarcoB *partially* I agree. The linked Q and the Qs within the linked Q all seem to describe *similar* although more specific problems. I'd particularly note http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/73489/resizing-or-moving-notebook-window-causes-manipulate-to-update-its-argument . Can anyone check if my implementation of the error is present in 10.0.2? For my part, I'll see, if the problem is observed without plotting functions later today. But I think we already have enough info to answer "Introduced in 10.x.x, fixed in 10.2"...

Comment: I'm just reluctant to do this myself without having the info first-hand (and without access to 10.2).

Comment: You might add that Kuba's answer to the linked duplicate has nothing to do with PlotTheme or DialogInput, but points out that the problem is with `Manipulator`.  So the generality of the problem is addressed in the answer, even if the original question contained red herrings.

Comment: @MichaelE2 yes, that was the point of my edit. My question *does* have an answer there, it just hasn't been explicitly asked :-D

Comment: Ah, I read the "however" as *contrasting* with Kuba's answer.