# Mathematica 10.2 Manipulate function settings problem

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction

I am trying `Manipulate` function in *Mathematica* 10.2. The problem is that when I move the slider the graph manipulates but when I click the + sign/expand button to see the value it automatically resets my slider to start position.

I have tried *Mathematica* 10 where this problem never occured.

Also I want to keep sliders in expanded form even after I reinitialize my `Manipulate` function if possible.

I know that I can expand the slider and then move it but the problem is I have to reinitialize my `Manipulate` function many times for various reasons and thus sliders reset all the time.

Kindly help me out if possible.

PS: I have tried the Bookmark setting its a little tedious.

Comment: You might add a minimal example to you question, to illustrate your problem. As far as I know and my tests show, the values do no longer (*Mathematica* 10.2, Windows 10) reset after clicking the Show Animation Controls button.

Comment: It was noticed ealier: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/82932/5478 it was marked as solved but I have no idea why...

Comment: @Kuba I remember this behavior well, and I had reported on reproducing it in the original question. I have since upgraded to 10.2 and indeed this behavior seems to have been fixed. I have not observed self-resetting sliders as described since the upgrade. I also cannot reproduce the problem in that question you linked any more, although I could with 10.1.

Comment: @Kuba It works properly for me.  V10.2, Mac OSX.  -- How do you find out what latest paclet update you have?  I wish there was a way to be notified when *M* is updated and to find out the current update version.  Probably there is....

Comment: Also related: [(82932)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/82932), [(88705)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88705)

Comment: If you want to see the value of a `Slider` use the option `Appearance -> "Labeled"`

Comment: Have you tried `Manipulate[x, {x, 0, 100, Appearance -> "Open"}]` per the documentation for `Manipulator` and `Manipulate`?

Comment: @Kuba Found `PacletInformation /@ PacletFindRemote["WolframAutoUpdate"]`.  My `Version` is 6.0.0.  No date though.

Comment: @MichaelE2 `"Version" -> "7.0.0"` :) and `Manipulator[1]` resets to `0` when opened.

Comment: @Kuba The code in http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/82932/5478 works fine for me, but  `Manipulator[1]` and `var = 1; Manipulator[Dynamic@var]` still reset. But `Manipulate[var, {{var, 75.}, 50., 100., 0.2}]` works fine. -- I voted to close as a duplicate, but now I think it should be closed as needing example code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @AVyas Could you give a simple example of a `Manipulate` that shows how you're using slider/manipulator?  Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelE2 For me it's the same bug with special case fixed. But I do not care how it is called/classified, I'm interested in a fix. :)

Comment: @Kuba Your example only resets when the initial value is greater than or equal to the upper end point (e.g., `Manipulator[0.9]` works fine). It seems opening `Manipulator[x., {a, b}]`, replaces the value `x` by `Mod[x, b-a, a]`.  In one way it makes sense, since you're opening (and activating) the animator component.