# Manipulate: strange behavior of Manipulator

Tags: manipulate, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.2 and fixed in 10.3**

---

Consider this simple code:

```
Manipulate[n, {n, 1, 5}]
```

When we evaluate it, we'll get

[image]

Now try to click on the little plus sign to expand the controls. Suddenly the slider will jump forward, in this case to value 4.

[image]

I'm almost certain that this is bug. Is there something we can do to mitigate this unexpected this behavior? I'm using *Mathematica* 10.2 64bit on Windows 10.

Comment: Reminiscent of a fixed bug: [(82932)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/82932/initializing-manipulator-value-within-dialoginput-version-10-1-only)

Comment: It's not exactly a fix, but a workaround would be to add [`Appearance -> "Open"`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Appearance.html) to the definition of your `Manipulate` variable (i.e. `{n, 1, 5, Appearance -> "Open"}`), so that the control will start out in the open state.

Comment: @MichaelE2 and again, I'd not say it was fixed :-/ http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/90028/5478. From the user side, there is still problem with opening `Manipulators`, they (I) probably don't care about details :)

Comment: @Kuba Yes, hence the link. Maybe we can file all under one big bug, "My Mathematica doesn't work." :)

Comment: @MarcoB `{n, 1, 5, Appearance -> "Open"}` as well as `{{n, 1}, 1, 5, Appearance -> "Open"}` doesn't work as a workaround for my *Mathematica* 10.2 on Win10. Did you try it?

Answer (score 1):

This bug has been fixed in *Mathematica* v10.3.

[image: Animation]