# Manipulator reset bug

Tags: manipulate, bugs, dynamic

**Bug introduced in 10.3 or earlier, fixed in 10.4.**

---

When the `+` opener is opened, two things happen:

```
x = 0;
Manipulator[Dynamic[x, (Print[#]; x = #) &], {-10, 0}]
```

[image]

1. the actual manipulator value `#` is set to be the minimum of the range;
2. the second argument of `Dynamic` gets evaluated.

However, when the range is set to e.g. `{-10, 10}`, the behavior is correct. `Manipulator` had a ragged history recently, check these related threads out:

- [Possible bug with Manipulate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88705/89)
- [Initializing Manipulator value within DialogInput (version 10.1 only)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/82932/89)
- [Mathematica 10.2 Manipulate function settings problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/90028/89)
- [Manipulate: strange behavior of Manipulator](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92860/89)
- [Manipulator bug](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/852622)

While somwe were ironed out, something more basic still lurks in `Manipulator`.

(*Mathematica* 10.3, Win 7 64)

Comment: Comments in [one of linked topics](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/90028/5478) are quite on point. I really like: `Manipulator[1]`

Comment: Thanks @Kuba, I'm aware of that, but I wanted to show that `Manipulator` not just resets the value but also evaluates anything else - which is scary, as always.

Comment: Using a range of `{-10, 0.01}` is interesting, too.

Comment: Submitted for TechSupport.

Comment: `Manipulate[x, {{x, 0}, -10, 0, TrackingFunction -> (x = #; Print[#]; &)}]` shows the same behavior.

Comment: Two more [funky situations](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Uw7Rg.gif).

Comment: [These are entertaining](http://i.stack.imgur.com/F6jm3.gif), too.

Comment: This works on v10.4 in Mac. Somebody should try it on Windows...

Comment: @kirma Haven't tried on 10.4. but works on Win 7 V10.4.1

Comment: But now there is another issue :D http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/852622

Comment: @Kuba Wow. That;s even more scary... I've included a link in the post for reference.

Comment: A [gif](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ThliX.gif) that demonstrates the new issue for this input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bug was fixed in version 10.4.0.0.