# Dynamic updating is triggered in the output cell when the input is edited

Tags: bugs, manipulate, editing

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and persisting through 11.0.1 or later**

---

Starting from Mathematica 10, there's a new feature: when you begin editing your input cell, its output becomes faded. A side effect of it is that in certain cases the output is dynamically updated. This results in annoyances like when you e.g. have made a mistake leading to messages being emitted and now try to edit the input cell to fix the mistake.

Here's a *simple* example:

```
Manipulate[ListPlot[Table[Sin[a x]/(a x), {x, -10, 10}], Joined -> True], {a, -10, 10}]
```

> (manipulator here)
>
> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.
>
> Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0 ComplexInfinity encountered.

Now try e.g. to replace `Sin[a x]/(a x)` with `Sinc[a x]`, and you'll get two more identical messages. In more complicated scenarios the manipulator may spit lots of messages, which you may have stopped by e.g. `Alt+.`. But once you start editing the input cell, all they will be emitted again.

This does not happen with every input.  It happens with `Manipulate`s that contain contain plotting functions in their code (even if the plot output is never displayed).

So my question is: how do I disable this (mis)feature of fading the output on editing input?

Comment: Could you not delete the output cell before you begin editing the input cell?

Comment: The output doesn't get re-evaluated.  Dynamic updating is triggered for some reason in this Manipulate (but not in general).  Perhaps you can update the title and description to avoid any confusion.

Comment: I've reported this when it first happened, FWIW.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Do you understand what is happening?  There's no general re-evaluation (that would be a disaster).  Not all `Dynamic` stuff gets updates (simple examples don't).  `Manipulate` is a bit special in that it doesn't actually evaluate, it just formats in a special way (`MakeBoxes`).  I tested and `MakeBoxes` are not called a second time when the output is faded.  What happens then?

Comment: Without the ListPlot it doesn't even happen.  Can't reproduce with simpler Manipulates.

Comment: Here's a simpler example: `Manipulate[
 Print["Evaluating"];
 ListPlot[{1, 2}];
 a,
 {a, -10, 10},
 TrackedSymbols -> {}
 ]`.  The `ListPlot` is critical, without it this doesn't happen.

Comment: @Szabolcs I'm not sure how I should change the title. I've seen a similar problem with `Plot3D` output, which on my slow i915-like GPU with ugly Mesa drivers appears to hang for some time again (as if it's re-generated) when I start editing the cell which generated it. So this all looks like a re-evaluation to me. Feel free to edit the title if you know how to formulate it correctly.

Comment: I think what really happens is a "re-formatting" (i.e. invocation of MakeBoxes), but I'm not sure yet.  E.g. select the output cell and press control-shift-N to convert to StandardForm (even if it is already StandardForm).  I suspect this is what really happens.

Comment: There's also the weird thing that in my example in the comment above, `Print` will print to the notebook directly.  However, if I remove `ListPlot`, it will print to the message window for some reason.  `Manipulate` appears to  switch to a different mode when it detects the ListPlot inside.  Maybe this has to do with `$ControlActiveSetting`, not sure.

Comment: @Szabolcs No, I don't know exactly what's happening. As you noticed, it seems to have to do with plotting (maybe exclusively). There are dynamically tracked variables with `*Plot[]` output, and something that gets changed when the output cell is dimmed must affect one of these variables and triggers an update.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Here's something weird: `Manipulate[x; Print@$PerformanceGoal, {x, 0, 1}]`  When the control is active, this should be Speed.  That gets printed in the messages window.  When the control stops being active, it reverts to Quality.  That is printed within the notebook itself.  This whole thing must have something to do with the detection of when quality must be reduced during changing the controls.  Usually this is necessary only when there are plotting functions.

Comment: Some more progress: whether something gets printed in the notebook or in the messages windows depends on the SynchronousUpdating setting of Manipulate.  True prints in the messages window.  The default Automatic setting switches depending on whether controls are active. This is why we see alternate printing in the notebook/messages window.

Comment: @Szabolcs The switch between output notebooks makes sense, since it's really hard to manipulate controls if the notebook is constantly being re-typeset. -- I think this will be hard to track down because the variable(s) that are changed when the output cell is dimmed are probably maintained internally by the FE. My LinkSnooper is broken, or I would look at that.

Comment: More progress: My initial hunch that what really happens is re-formatting was incorrect.  It is a simple dynamic updating without re-formatting (re-running MakeBoxes).  This is my conclusion after setting ``Manipulate`Dump`DebugPrint = Print`` and trying editing the input, and also trying re-formatting through ctrl-shift-N.  Only re-formatting triggers debug messages.

Comment: I give up. I don't know.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/73489/resizing-or-moving-notebook-window-causes-manipulate-to-update-its-argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a workaround, unless you like plot themes: `PlotTheme -> None`.

```
n = 0;
Dynamic[n]

Manipulate[
 1/x; 
 ++n;
 Plot[Sin[n t], {t, 0, Pi}, PlotTheme -> None],
 {x, 0, 1}, TrackedSymbols :> {x}]
```

I reported this in October, 2014 (CASE:1866485).  One of the developers said he thought it had to do with a dependency related to plot themes being set that shouldn't be.  That gave me the idea for the workaround above.

---

One can also set `$PlotTheme = None` as a workaround. If the `Manipulate` has already been executed, a new `$PlotTheme` will not take effect until ***after*** the next time `Manipulate` updates the plot.

```
$PlotTheme = None;  (* execute after Manipulate to see it work after the fact *)

Manipulate[1/x;
 ListPlot@Table[Sin[(1 + x) t]^2, {t, 0, 10}],
 {x, 0, 1}, TrackedSymbols :> {x}]
```