# ParametricPlot causes Manipulate to update when local & external variable share the same name

Tags: plotting, manipulate, dynamic

Here is a strange behavior reminding me of a [previous bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73489/19960) when `Manipulate` updates without reason, but it is probably not the same reason here and seems to be specific to `ParametricPlot`.
(My specs:  OSX, MMA 11.2)

First evaluate this command:

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[r*{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotRange -> {-2, 2}, PlotTheme -> None, 
  PlotLabel -> RandomReal[]], {r, 1, 2}]
```

then observe that this previous cell updates when you evaluate in a separate cell:

```
t=1
```

If you set `t` to another value, `Manipulate` will evaluates again.

What causes that behavior and is there a workaround ?

(Note that I set `PlotTheme->None` just in case that option would be responsible for that. Also there is no problem with `Plot`for example so it seems to be function specific.)
)

[image]

**Update**

It becomes even more strange as other `Manipulate` begin to update the same way only when the `Manipulate + ParametricPlot` is present:

[image]

You can check that if you delete  the output of `Manipulate[ParametricPlot[...]`, the `Manipulate[Table[...` won't update anymore if you change the value of `t` (actually it will update only once then no more ...).

Comment: It looks like a flaw with how `Dynamic` decides which symbols are supposed to be tracked. Or which not to include, it can handle e.g. `Module[{t},` or `Plot` (I see it is triggered once) but fails for `ParametricPlot`, `PolarPlot`. Just an observation.

Comment: @Kuba I added an another observation: it seems the tracking problem is not local. It explains also your observation `i see it is triggered once` ...

Comment: I'd report this, btw `Dynamic[ParametricPlot[t,{t,0,1}]]` is enough to show it so that we don't have to think about all fancy stuff behind Manipulate.