# Notebook's position / WindowMargins interfere with Dynamic @ CurrentValue @ WindowSize

Tags: bugs, front-end, dynamic, notebooks

**Bug introduced in 10.4 or earlier and persists through 12.1**

[CASE:3993149]

---

In most cases dragging notebook's window around does not affect its `WindowSize`.

Why is this `Dynamic` triggered then?

```
Dynamic[
  {RandomReal[], CurrentValue[WindowSize]}
,  TrackedSymbols :> {}
]
```

[image]

The problem is closely related to this one:

[Notebook's WindowSize interference with contents' Dynamic ImageSizes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/61659/5478)

and looking on how it was handled by WRI I don't have high hopes for fixing it.

The question is, can this be avoided/optimized? Is this a bug, or did I miss something?

Comment: Do you expect the dynamic to update when changing the window's size even though you have `TrackedSymbols :> {}`?

Comment: @Coolwater I'm fine with skipping this but I guess it should not harm because `CurrentValue @ WindowSize` or `Option`  is not a symbol in this context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Workaround:

```
Row[{Dynamic[{RandomReal[], cws}, TrackedSymbols :> {}],
  Pane[Invisible[Dynamic[cws = CurrentValue[WindowSize]]], ImageSize -> {0, 0}]}]
```

though maybe include `cws` in `TrackedSymbols`.

Edit by OP:

Here is the same idea implemented in a more idiomatic manner:

```
DynamicModule[{cws}
, DynamicWrapper[
    Dynamic[{RandomReal[], cws}]
  , FEPrivate`Set[cws, CurrentValue[WindowSize]]
  ]
]
```

`Dynamic` is triggered only when `cws` **changes** as opposed to having assigned (the same) value.

Additionally `` FEPrivate`Set `` and making `cws` a `DynamicModule` variable, allows us to do this part completely FronEnd side. We didn't get rid of original spam but now it does not need to waste time and links by going to kernel and back, only the main `Dynamic` content will need to go there.

This can be confirmed using LinkSnooper.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this counts as an answer; perhaps it just casts more darkness on the issue.

First your example can be reduced to

```
Dynamic[{RandomReal[], CurrentValue[WindowSize]}]
```

Second and perhaps even more annoying is

```
DynamicModule[{n = 0},
  Dynamic[{n++, CurrentValue[WindowSize]}, TrackedSymbols :> {}]]
```

which updates `n` when the window is moved.

My take on this is that the front-end is getting events from the OS whenever you move the window, and these events (which are probably something like or equivalent to {{left, top}, {right, bottom}} in screen coordinates) cause the front-end to recompute `WindowSize` for each event instance. Further, it would seem that can't be turned off by the user with `TrackedSymbols :> {}`, so any expression wrapped with `Dynamic` containing `WindowSize` is going to be evaluated as the window moves.

Comment: Yep, that unfortunately is the case :(

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is

```
Dynamic[{RandomReal[], Dynamic@CurrentValue[WindowSize]}]
```