# Stretch Grid to fit width of containing object?

Tags: grid-layouts

How can I stretch this Grid to the width of the encapsulating Panel (so that "right"  floats on the right side? I want to achieve something along the lines of the menu at the top of the Documentation notebooks.

```
Panel[
 Grid[
  {{"left", "nextToLeft", "right"}},
  Alignment -> {{Left, Left, Right}, Baseline}],
 ImageSize -> Full]
```

Looks like this now:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `Scaled` item sizes but that still requires you to manually get it right:

```
Panel[Grid[{{"left", "nextToLeft", "right"}}, 
  Alignment -> {{Left, Left, Right}, Baseline}, 
  ItemSize -> {{Scaled[.1], Scaled[.1], Scaled[.8]}}, Frame -> All, 
  Spacings -> {0, 0}], ImageSize -> Full]
```

So the way I usually do it is to wrap the right hand item in `Pane`

```
Panel[Grid[{
   {"left", "nextToLeft", 
    Framed@Pane["right", {Full, All}, Alignment -> {Right, Center}, 
      ImageMargins -> 0]}
   }, Alignment -> {{Left, Left, Right}, Baseline}],
 ImageSize -> Full]
```

I've added a frame so you can see what is happening:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `ItemSize -> Fit`:

```
 Panel[Grid[{{"left", "nextToLeft", "right"}}, 
       ItemSize ->Fit,
       Alignment -> {{Left, Left, Right}, Baseline},  
       Frame -> False, Spacings -> {0, 0}], 
    ImageSize -> Full]
```

Mixed settings like `ItemSize -> {{Scaled[.1], 15, Fit}}` also work:

```
 Column[
   Panel[Grid[{{"left", "nextToLeft", "right"}}, 
              Alignment -> {{Left, Center, Right}, Baseline}, ItemSize -> #, 
              Frame -> False, Spacings -> {0, 0}], 
        ImageSize ->Full] & /@ 
   {Fit, {{{15, 20, Fit}}}, {{{Fit, 20, Fit}}}, {{{Scaled[.1], 15, Fit}}}}]
```

[image]

**Update:** Need help locating references in the docs for `ItemSize->Fit`. I am quite sure I have seen it somewhere in the documentation, but could not find anything using the usual keywords.

The only example I currently have is burried in [this great answer by Mike](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7499) to a different question (thanks Mr.Wizard).

Comment: Another really useful feature that does not appear to be in the Documentation. (Or is it?) Thanks.

Comment: @mfvonh, I am sure I have seen this used somewhere in the docs. But to my surprise I could not find this setting for `ItemSize` when I searched with keywords `Itemsize->Fit`, `Fit` or `ItemSize` in the docs.

Comment: This works in version 7, where Mike's method unfortunately appears not to. +1

Comment: I note that Mike used `Fit` himself here: [(7499)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7499)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, good to know that it is not a Version 9 thing. Amazing you could find Mike's answer using `Fit`:) I had checked the reference pages for `DockedCells` but could not find any examples using `Fit` there.