# Advancing slides with Mathematica on a Mac laptop

Tags: slideshows, user-interface

I am giving my first presentation with Mathematica, and am having trouble figuring out how to advance the slides from my laptop keyboard.  In most other environments, some pair of the arrow keys works.  I have tried the alt-PageDn combination, but no luck.

I am running Mavericks on a 2014 MacBook Pro.  Is there any way to re-assign key combinations?  I hate relying on the top toolbar to advance slides.  Related to this, is there any way to re-position the slide tool bar to the bottom of the slides?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems to be answered here:http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10733/changing-scroll-rate-for-page-down-key

Comment: Thanks.  I saw this but was hoping that there was a way to do this without keyboard re-mapping outside of Mathematica.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As listed [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/KeyboardShortcutListing.html), using <kbd>page up</kbd> and <kbd>page down</kbd> *without* pressing <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> (alt) on a 2012 iMac attached to the Apple keyboard works with a demo presentation (once you enter SlideShow view). On a MacBook keyboard, this would be <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> (note that <kbd>page up</kbd> and <kbd>page down</kbd> are **not** equivalent to <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>).

I haven't worked out a way to bind the `StartPresentation` command to a shortcut, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209405/customizing-mathematica-shortcuts) question seems like it might have some good suggestions.

I found [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7458/easy-button-or-hot-key-to-switch-between-working-and-slideshow-screen-enviro/7459#7459) answer, which can get you into the SlideShow view environment, and from there you just have to jump to full screen (<kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>). 
If you want to set that up on OS X, something like [KeyboardMaestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) or [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.net) would probably do the trick, especially if you're using a wireless mouse or presentation remote. Disclaimer: While I use BTT on a daily basis (it's free and does all the things I require), I have never used KM. I have heard nothing but good things about it.