Placing Button in Docked Cell That Dynamically Updates an Attached Cell and the Notebook's Bracket Margins
The following code creates a button that animates the opening and closing of a panel on the right side of the notebook.  Thanks to Kuba.
(*Initial Cleanup - Deletes any existing attached and/or docked cells*)
NotebookDelete[Cells[InputNotebook[], AttachedCell -> True]];
SetOptions[InputNotebook[], DockedCells -> {}];

(*buttons to be included in attatched cell*)
mybuttons = 
  Panel[Column[
    Button[Style[#, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
       FrontEndTokenExecute[InputNotebook[], "Style", #], 
       Appearance -> "Palette", ImageSize -> 120] & /@ {"Title", 
      "Subtitle", "Subsubtitle", "Section", "Subsection", 
      "Subsubsection", "Text", "Code", "Input"}, Spacings -> 0, 
    Alignment -> Center], ImageSize -> {150, All}, 
   Background -> LightBlue, Alignment -> Center];

(*Creates attached cell with dynamic bracket margin*)
w = 0; 
AttachCell[InputNotebook[], 
  Pane[mybuttons, ImageSize -> {Dynamic[w]/150 *145, All}], {Right, 
   Top}, 0, {Right, Top}];


(*Creates button that animates change to bracket margin*)
DynamicModule[{running = False, direction = Forward},
 Button[Row[{Animator[
     Dynamic[w, {Automatic, (CurrentValue[
           InputNotebook[], {CellBracketOptions, 
            "Margins"}] = {0, #}) &}], {0, 150, 1}, 
     AppearanceElements -> "None", 
     AnimationDirection -> Dynamic@direction, AnimationRate -> 600, 
     AnimationRepetitions -> 1, AnimationRunning -> Dynamic@running], 
    "Format"}], direction = If[w == 0, Forward, Backward];
  running = True, Enabled -> Dynamic[! running]]]

See the code in action below.  As you can see, I have emulated the typical hiding and showing of buttons that you would see in a typical word processing program like Word or Pages.  This functionality cleans up the look up my lecture notebooks as I don't need to keep all buttons visible in a docked cell.

I am trying to improve upon this code in two ways:

Localize the dynamic variable w to the the current notebook, so that the button only affects the current button notebook and not other open notebooks.
Place the button in the notebook's docked cell. The button above works great until I try placing it in a docked cell.

Edit: Mike Honeychurch offered a solution to 1.  Question 2 remains.

You can make the CellContext specific to a given Notebook, which in turn makes variables notebook specific rather than global

Take a look at TaggingRules, it is what is used for such things in documentation notebooks etc. CurrentValue[nb_, {TaggingRules, "w"}] = value_

re:#2 please see this https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7458/easy-button-or-hot-key-to-switch-between-working-and-slideshow-screen-enviro/7499#7499

Below is a solution using tagging rules. This seems like a cleaner solution as the all variables are localized to the notebook, so I don't need to mess with contexts. Thanks Kuba!  As you can see, the 2nd argument of Dynamic came in handy to update the Tagging Rule in the Animator. The code is probably inefficient, as I'm learning to code in my spare time.  Any suggestions to clean it up are appreciated.  Thirsty to learn.
 (*Initial Cleanup*)
NotebookDelete[Cells[InputNotebook[], AttachedCell -> True]];
CurrentValue[InputNotebook[], {TaggingRules}] = <||>;
SetOptions[InputNotebook[], DockedCells -> {}];

(*Panel of Buttons for attached cell*)
mybuttons = 
  Panel[Column[
    Button[Style[#, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
       FrontEndTokenExecute[InputNotebook[], "Style", #], 
       Appearance -> "Palette", ImageSize -> 120] & /@ {"Title", 
      "Subtitle", "Subsubtitle", "Section", "Subsection", 
      "Subsubsection", "Text", "Code", "Input"}, Spacings -> 0, 
    Alignment -> Center], ImageSize -> {150, 1200}, 
   Background -> Gray, Alignment -> {Center, Top}];

SetOptions[InputNotebook[],
 
 (*Set Docked Cell with Button Animator that sets tagging rules for w*)
 DockedCells -> Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[
     DynamicModule[{running = False, direction = Forward, w = 0}, 
      Button[Row[{Animator[
          Dynamic[w, (w = #; 
             CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {TaggingRules, "w"}] =
               Dynamic@w) &], {0, 150, 1}, 
          AppearanceElements -> "None", 
          AnimationDirection -> Dynamic@direction, 
          AnimationRate -> 1000, AnimationRepetitions -> 1, 
          AnimationRunning -> Dynamic@running], 
         Dynamic@If[w == 150, Style["Format", Red], "Format"]}], 
       direction = If[w == 0, Forward, Backward]; running = True, 
       Enabled -> Dynamic[! running], BaselinePosition -> Axis, 
       Appearance -> "AbuttingLeft", ImageSize -> {All, 28}]]]]],
 
 (*Set cell bracket margin equal to w taggingrule*)
 CellBracketOptions -> {"Margins" -> {0, 
     Dynamic@CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {TaggingRules, "w"}]}},
 
 (*Set up attached cell with width w taggingrule*)
 NotebookDynamicExpression ->
  (AttachCell[InputNotebook[], 
    Pane[mybuttons, 
     ImageSize -> {Dynamic[
        CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {TaggingRules, "w"}]], 
       All}], {Right, Top}, 0, {Right, Top}])
 ]


Mike's Solution for Question #1 works.  I tried using Kuba's suggestion for Question #2.  It worked, but the animation freezes.  It does seem like like TaggingRules is the way to go, but I can't seem to make it work smoothly.  In any case, the following works.
(*Initial Cleanup-Deletes any existing attached and/or docked cells*)
NotebookDelete[Cells[InputNotebook[], AttachedCell -> True]];
SetOptions[InputNotebook[], DockedCells -> {}];

(*buttons to be included in attatched cell*)
mybuttons = 
  Panel[Column[
    Button[Style[#, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
       FrontEndTokenExecute[InputNotebook[], "Style", #], 
       Appearance -> "Palette", ImageSize -> 120] & /@ {"Title", 
      "Subtitle", "Subsubtitle", "Section", "Subsection", 
      "Subsubsection", "Text", "Code", "Input"}, Spacings -> 0, 
    Alignment -> Center], ImageSize -> {150, All}, 
   Background -> LightBlue, Alignment -> Center];

(*Attachedcell with initial width 2*)
w = 2;
AttachCell[InputNotebook[], 
  Pane[mybuttons, ImageSize -> {Dynamic@w, All}], {Right, Top}, 
  0, {Right, Top}];

(*Create button in docked cell that runs animation controlling width \
of attached cell and cell bracket margin*)
SetOptions[InputNotebook[],
 DockedCells -> Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[
     DynamicModule[{running = False, direction = Forward},
      Button[Row[{Animator[Dynamic[w], {2, 150, 1},
          AppearanceElements -> "None", 
          AnimationDirection -> Dynamic@direction, 
          AnimationRate -> 1000, AnimationRepetitions -> 1, 
          AnimationRunning -> Dynamic@running], "Format"}], 
       direction = If[w == 2, Forward, Backward]; running = True,
       Enabled -> Dynamic[! running],
       BaselinePosition -> Axis, 
       Appearance -> "AbuttingLeft",
       ImageSize -> {All, 28}]]
     ]]],
 CellBracketOptions -> {"Margins" -> {0, Dynamic@w}}]



+1 Is there a way to make this bar persistent across sessions in a notebook?

@E.Chan-López Take a look at the other solution.  I used a tagging rule stored in the notebook.  I think it can be made persistent by using a tagging rule stored in the frontend.
