# Dynamically splitting Disks with Mouseover

Tags: graphics, dynamic

I've recently stumbled across this site: [Koalas to the Max](http://www.koalastothemax.com/), and the first thought that came to my mind was "I want to recreate this with Mathematica".

As a first step I tried to create a `Disk` that splits itself up into four disks, when the mouse cursor touches it. Those four disks should in turn split themselves up. Here's what I have so far:

```
makeDisks[pos_] := makeDisks[1, pos]
makeDisks[level_, pos_] :=
 Module[{
   disk = Disk[pos, 1/level]},
  Mouseover[Dynamic@disk, Dynamic[disk = makeDisks[level + 1, #] & /@ 
   (pos + # & /@ (1/(2 level)) Tuples[{-1, 1}, 2])]]
  ]

(* test with the following *)

 Graphics[{makeDisks[1]},
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
```

For the first disk this seems to work just as I want it. For later steps, however, I got the positioning wrong and some of the disks go back to larger ones, when another one is touched. How can these issues be fixed?

As a next step I want to add colors to the disks. Maybe this can be done by using `MapIndexed` with `makeDisks` on the `ImageData` of some image. The colors in each step should probably be the mean values of appropriate subsets of the image data.

Any help to move this little program forward is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's a simple way using buttons, for some reason `AutoAction` is not working so you have to click, anyone know why?

```
nextPos[p_, r_] := {p + # r/2, r/2} & /@ Tuples[{1, -1}, 2]

DynamicModule[{diskList = {{ {0, 0}, 1}}},
 Graphics[Dynamic[
   Button[{ColorData["Rainbow"][Last@#], Disk @@ #},
      diskList = DeleteCases[Join[diskList, nextPos @@ #], #]
      ,AutoAction -> True
      ] & /@ diskList]]
 ]
```

[image: circles]

The coloring is only based on depth (radius)

Basing color on underlying image:

```
background = ImageCrop[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Peppers"}], AspectRatio -> 1];

DynamicModule[{diskList = {{{0, 0}, 1}}}, Graphics[Dynamic[
   Button[{RGBColor@ImageValue[background,First@#, DataRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}],
       Disk @@ #} 
     ,diskList = DeleteCases[Join[diskList, nextPos @@ #], #]
     ,AutoAction -> True] & /@ diskList]]]
```

[image: pepper]

Using code from @Szabolcs comment it's possible to split the disks without clicking:

```
(* Create at most 2^6=64 disks in a row *) 
rmin = 2^-6;
DynamicModule[{diskList = {{{0., 0.}, 1.}}}, Graphics[Dynamic[
  EventHandler[{RGBColor@ImageValue[background, First@#, DataRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], 
                Disk @@ #}
    ,{"MouseMoved" :>
      If[Last@# > rmin, diskList =DeleteCases[Join[diskList, nextPos @@ #], #]]}
   ] & /@ diskList]]
]
```

Comment: (+1) AutoAction doesn't work here either.  But even if it did, wouldn't it trigger a split on every move?  In the original, a split is only triggered when the mouse moves into a disk the first time (but not when the mouse happens to be over a newly generated disk)

Comment: @Szabolcs Indeed, potentially it would also create a crazy amount of disks, so would need some minimum `r` limit

Comment: I mean, this would happen: `DynamicModule[{diskList = {{{0, 0}, 1}}}, 
 Graphics[Dynamic[
   EventHandler[{ColorData["Rainbow"][Last@#], 
       Disk @@ #}, {"MouseMoved" :> (diskList = 
          DeleteCases[Join[diskList, nextPos @@ #], #])}] & /@ 
    diskList]]]`

Comment: Sorry, there's a stupid copy/paste problem on OS X that always bites me.

Comment: A related question: "What's the fixed point of overlap for the parent and all child disks, so that I can just keep my mouse at one point and keep clicking?" :D #lazy

Comment: Autoaction seems not working with Graphical Buttons. Test it `Module[{i = Disk[]}, #@
    Button[Dynamic@i, Dynamic[i = Rectangle[]], 
     AutoAction -> True]] & /@ {Identity, Graphics}`

Comment: This is awesome, thanks! I'll wait until tomorrow to see if somebody comes up with something else, but after the latest update, this pretty much nails it! :) I really have to look into `EventHandler`. Never used it before...

Comment: Sadly it gets progressively slower as the number of disks increases...

Comment: I just ran across this. Fun to play with.

Answer (score 15):

Alternative

```
DynamicModule[{visited = False}, 
    Dynamic@EventHandler[
      If[visited, 
       Thread@Translate[#0@#, {1, -1}~Tuples~2]~Scale~
        0.5, {ColorData["Rainbow"]@Random[], #}], 
      "MouseEntered" :> (visited = True)]] &[Disk[]] // Graphics
```

Other version. Works "more or less" fine. Read comments

```
SetAttributes[translateOnHover, HoldFirst];
s : translateOnHover[onVar_, animationLength_, animationRate_: 200][
   prim_] := 
 With[{creationTime = Clock[Infinity]~Refresh~None}, 
  DynamicModule[{visited = False}, 
   Dynamic@If[visited, 
     With[{visitedTime = Clock[Infinity]~Refresh~None}, 
      With[{currentTime := 
         1/animationLength (Clock[{0, visitedTime + animationLength, 
              1`/animationRate}, visitedTime + animationLength, 1] - 
            visitedTime)}, 
       Thread@Translate[s, ({1, -1}~Tuples~2) /. 
           pt : {_, _} :> Dynamic[pt currentTime]]~Scale~
        Dynamic[currentTime /. t_ :> 1 - t + 0.5 t^2]]], 
     EventHandler[{ColorData["Rainbow"]@Random[], prim}, 
      "MouseEntered" :> 
       If[onVar && 
         Refresh[Clock[Infinity], None] - creationTime > 
          animationLength, visited = True]]]]]

With[{animationLength = 0.8, animationRate = 80}, 
  DynamicModule[{on = False}, 
   Column[{Row[{Button["Start", on = True, Enabled -> Dynamic[! on]], 
       Spacer[20], 
       Button["Stop", on = False, Enabled -> Dynamic[on]]}], 
     Graphics[
      translateOnHover[on, animationLength, animationRate][Disk[]], 
      ImageSize -> Medium, PlotRange -> 1.2 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]}, 
    Alignment -> Center]]] // Panel
```

Comment: Nice use of `#0`!

Comment: What is MouseEntered?  Is there a link somewhere to a list of undocumented EventHandler events?

Comment: @Szabolcs it is triggered when the mouse enters, there's also MouseExited. I'm trying to remember where I got that from.

Comment: Re your last edit: During animations I get a lot of "shaking", it seems like the plot range may be changing rapidly.  For disks next to the edge the whole plot is shaking, for others only the animated part.  Do you see this too?

Comment: @Szabolcs, I see only a tiny bit of shaking, probably less than what you see. The PlotRange is explicitly set in the last line, so I have no idea why that happens.

Comment: @Szabolcs does it get better by increasing the plot range? (changing the last line from `PlotRange->1.2 ...` to, say `PlotRange-> 1.5 ...`

Comment: @Rojo I'll try that but in the meantime please see [this](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/38623/Untitled.mov)  One weird thing is that it wasn't shaking nearly as much during the screen recording as it normally does.  EDIT: changing the PlotRange doesn't help.  But I need to be back to work now.

Comment: @Szabolcs I see that, and so far, no clue what it may be. Let me know if you think of something

Comment: @Szabolcs Perhaps it's the explicit nested translations and scalings that link all together. Blame that `Normal` that doesn't work. I'll try to do it "by hand" and see if it works

Comment: +1. But, Sometimes the disks move to the wrong position (see the white hole in the lover left corner).

Comment: @Szabolcs It doesn't shake for me, but I think I understand what you mean by shaking and it might be a mac specific issue with dynamic stuff. Sometimes your palette shakes in the corner of my screen...

Comment: @Szabolcs, [look at this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6225/109)

Comment: @rm-rf The "shaking" is definitely not mac specific. I get it too. (Windows 7, Mma 8)