# Optimizing a bubble art code

Tags: code-review, generative-art

Based on [that website](http://www.koalastothemax.com/) I wanted to recreate the same effect using *Mathematica* but with any picture given by the user. Thus I came up with the following code:

```
DynamicModule[{list, r, divcir, parts, execpt , posC = {}, tab, col, center, i, pm, rect, rectvalue, coloring},
 i = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Elaine"}];
 (* user should crop it in a square before, but in case: *)
 i = ImageCrop[i, {Min@ImageDimensions@i, Min@ImageDimensions@i}];
 center = #/2 & /@ ImageDimensions@i;
 list = {center};
 (r[#] = First@center) & /@ list;
 (col[#] = Mean@Mean@ImageData@i) & /@ list;
 Dynamic@Graphics[{coloring@col[#], Button[Disk[#, r[#]],
       {(* ==size/position of each disks== *)
        posC = #; (* get the clicked disk *)
        list = execpt[parts@{list, divcir[r[#], posC]}, posC];(* divide by four the clicked disk *)
        (r[#] = r[posC]/2) & /@ divcir[r[posC], posC];(* halve the radius of the next four disks *)
        (* ==color of each disks== *)
        rect = Transpose /@ (pm[#, r@#] & /@ list);(* area corresponding to the disks *)
        rectvalue = Mean@ImageValue[i, (Span @@@ rect[[#]])] & /@ Range@Length@rect; (* color of the rect *)
        ClearAll@col;(* assigning values to the variable col *)
        Set @@@ ((col[#] -> #2) & @@@ Thread[{list, rectvalue}]);
        }]} & /@ list, ImageSize -> 350]

 , Initialization :>
  (divcir[r_, {x0_, y0_}] := {{-r/2 + x0, r/2 + y0}, {r/2 + x0, r/2 + y0}, {r/2 + x0, -r/2 + y0}, {-r/2 + x0, -r/2 + y0}};
   parts[lst_] := Partition[Flatten@lst, 2];
   execpt[lst_, elm_] := Cases[lst, Except@elm];
   pm[a_, b_] := {a - b, a + b};
   coloring[col_] := If[Length@col == 0, GrayLevel@col, RGBColor@col];
   )]
```

> [image: Subdividing circles]

By clicking over and over one would get:

> [image: Elaine]

---

My issues are:

1. It gets slower and slower when the number of disks increases since I am calculating the color of each disks each time, hence my question regarding the optimization.
2. It is somehow *boring* for the user to click on each disks, the [idea](http://www.koalastothemax.com/) would be to use [`Mouseover`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Mouseover.html) but I only came up with crashing *Mathematica*.

Any help on these two issues would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: Closely related: [Dynamically splitting Disks with Mouseover](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19843/121)

Comment: Related regarding the `Mouseover` indeed, I think my major issue here is the calculation of the colors slowing down everything. And it is from the same website as well.., snap. That would have saved me lots of time!

Comment: Well, this is basically a duplicate.., it has been already answered with an much shorter code. And the speed issue is present as well.

Comment: @Öskå So I voted to close. However I think it mustn't be deleted because it contains several interesting keywords for internet search (bubbles, generative, etc)

Comment: Maybe changing the title and tags of the other one & deleting this one would be possible as well.

Comment: I think duplicates should typically stay undeleted for the reasons belisarius mentioned.

Comment: So be it. Even if I feel like a gigantic noob with my gigantic code.