# Event action default before custom

Tags: front-end, customization

I want to change how a notebook files save. The basic framework I'm using for this is:

```
SetOptions[
 EvaluationNotebook[],
 NotebookEventActions ->
  {
   {"MenuCommand", "Save"} :>
    (NotebookSave[]; $action)
   }
 ]
```

Because with `PassEventsDown->True` the `$action` gets called before the `NotebookSave`.

This is ugly and a little bit hazardous, though. Is there any way to have it otherwise? Can I trigger the event to save first, then do the `$action` with `PassEventsDown->True`?

Answer (score 6):

So I found the answer to this in [an old answer of mine](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/133137/38205). The trick is to use the undocumented `EvaluationOrder`.

By assigning `EvaluationOrder->After` our event gets called after the built-in one. To test this we can try the following. First, see what happens with `"ModifiedInMemory"` with the explicit order we started with:

```
SetOptions[
 EvaluationNotebook[],
 NotebookEventActions ->
  {
   {"MenuCommand", "Save"} :>
    (
     NotebookSave[];
     Print[Lookup[NotebookInformation[], "ModifiedInMemory"]]
     )
   }
 ]

(* prints False on save events *)
```

With no `EvaluationOrder`:

```
SetOptions[
 EvaluationNotebook[],
 NotebookEventActions ->
  {
   {"MenuCommand", "Save"} :>
    (
     Print[Lookup[NotebookInformation[], "ModifiedInMemory"]]
     ),
   PassEventsDown -> True
   }
 ]

(* prints True on save events *)
```

With no `EvaluationOrder->After`:

```
SetOptions[
 EvaluationNotebook[],
 NotebookEventActions ->
  {
   {"MenuCommand", "Save"} :>
    (
     Print[Lookup[NotebookInformation[], "ModifiedInMemory"]]
     ),
   PassEventsDown -> True,
   EvaluationOrder->After
   }
 ]

(* prints False on save events *)
```

This also works for [`EventHandler`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EventHandler.html) and [`CellEventActions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellEventActions.html)

Comment: It is used in stylesheet toolbar to calculate content menu on MouseEntered if I remember correctly.

Comment: @Kuba makes sense. I found it in some input fields myself. I had simply never seen it before and thought it should be on the site.

Comment: @Kuba did you know about `ToggleMenuItem`? I just saw it in the `ComponentwiseContextMenu` and it seems potentially useful if I ever make an application with a custom menu on one of its boxes.

Comment: Yes, thanks for posting this. About `ToggleMenuItem` this I didn't know. Would be nice to get feedback from WRI about the future of such findings. I don't like to use too deep stuff as I usually need it to work on win/mac/player/future versions.