# Question about usage of Style as Dynamic object

Tags: front-end, dynamic

I saw a `Dynamic` snippet in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8606/17), which wrote

> ```
> DynamicModule[{font}, 
>  Row[{PopupMenu[Dynamic[font], 
>     FE`Evaluate[FEPrivate`GetPopupList["MenuListFonts"]]], Spacer[20],
>     Style["The quick brown fox", 20, FontFamily -> font]}]]
> ```

Things confusing me most are that I thought the `Style[ ... ]` part should be wrapped in a `Dynamic[ ... ]`, but to my surprise it doesn't need one in the above code for (at least looks like) working correctly!

So I did some experiments in Mathematica 9:

**Working:**

```
DynamicModule[{col},
 Row[{
   PopupMenu[Dynamic[col], {Red -> 1, Blue -> 2}],
   Style["text", FontColor -> col, 20]
   }]
 ]

DynamicModule[{col},
 Row[{
   PopupMenu[
    Dynamic[col], {RGBColor[1, 0, 0] -> 1, RGBColor[0, 0, 1] -> 2}],
   "\!\(\*StyleBox[\"\\\"text\\\"\", Rule[FontColor, $CellContext`col$$]]\)"
   }]
 ]
```

**Not Working:**

```
DynamicModule[{col},
 Row[{
   PopupMenu[Dynamic[col], {Red -> 1, Blue -> 2}],
   col
   }]
 ]

DynamicModule[{col},
 Row[{
   PopupMenu[Dynamic[col], {Red -> 1, Blue -> 2}],
   Style["text", col, 20]
   }]
 ]

DynamicModule[{col},
 Row[{
   PopupMenu[
    Dynamic[col], {RGBColor[1, 0, 0] -> 1, RGBColor[0, 0, 1] -> 2}],
   "\!\(\*StyleBox[\"\\\"text\\\"\", $CellContext`col$$]\)"
   }]
 ]
```

**Questions:**

- Why is this `Dynamic`-wrapping-free behavior of `Style`? My personal suspicion is, a *proper* form (*i.e.* with explicit option names) of `Style[ ... ]` is handled by the FrontEnd. Please correct me if I'm wrong.
- Should I take advantage of this feature(?), or should I generally avoid it?

Comment: Even stranger: `DynamicModule[{col}, Row[{PopupMenu[Dynamic[col], {Red->1, Blue->2}], Plot[x^2, {x, -2, 2}, BaseStyle->{FontColor->col}]}]]`  -- the color change is off by one, if you toggle back and forth.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Interesting... Need to leave for an hour for urgency, will investigating after. Thank you for your instance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You definitely should not rely on this behavior.

There is one and only one proper way to get dynamic behavior for the rhs of a front end option, and that is to wrap `Dynamic` around the entirety of the option.  The only exceptions to this rule at present are certain options which will assume the `Dynamic` if one doesn't exist, such as `CellDynamicExpression` and friends.  There might also be some options which correctly allow `Dynamic` in a subexpression that I'm not thinking of.

So why does it work?  The FE has to put *something* in for the value if it gets a poorly formed or erroneous expression for an option.  The handling of such cases is sometimes a little sloppy and not entirely consistent.  There was a thought in v6 on the part of some developers, for example, that not wrapping a `Dynamic` would cause a one-time evaluation that might go to the kernel.  This was never documented, and the implementation was sloppy; I wouldn't be surprised if it's that feature which led to the behavior you're seeing here.

The code you quoted was written by me.  The lack of a `Dynamic` was a simple oversight on my part, enhanced by the fact that it actually worked.  You shouldn't read anything into the missing `Dynamic` as some super-secret feature or highly advanced programming technique which should be emulated.  I make mistakes, too.  Lots of them.

I've edited [the answer you linked to](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2572/what-is-the-complete-list-of-valid-front-end-tokens/8606#8606) in the hope of reducing future confusion.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation! You have fulfilled my curiosity!