# How to select only NotebookObjects that are referring to ordinary notebooks? (not palettes etc.)

Tags: front-end, notebooks, syntax, filtering

There is of course function

```
Notebooks[]
```

> [image]

But, unfortunatelly it hasn't got useful options in this context.

**My question is how to pick `Notebooks` excluding:**

- Help,
- Palettes,
- Packages,
- Messages,
- Text notebooks.

---

Parsing `Notebook/CellInformation` functions, I've found `Patterns`, e.g.:

```
ClearAttributes[Developer`CellInformation, ReadProtected]
DownValues @ Developer`CellInformation
```

> ```
> [...]  (_FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook | _FrontEnd`InputNotebook | 
>  _FrontEnd`ButtonNotebook | _FrontEnd`EvaluationNotebook | 
>  _FrontEnd`MessagesNotebook | _FrontEnd`HelpBrowserNotebook | 
>  _FrontEnd`ClipboardNotebook) | (_CellObject | _FrontEnd`CellObject) [...]
> ```

Those patterns seem to be what I need but I've not managed to use them. Any tips or another solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the information given by `AbsoluteOptions` will be enough to distinguish one type of Notebook from another.

To investigate the differences among the option values of different Notebooks, we first prepare all six types of Notebooks:

```
nblist = Complement[Notebooks[], {EvaluationNotebook[]}]
```

[image: test notebooks]

Then we extract all of their `AbsoluteOptions`, and delete those which are the same among different types of Notebooks.

Then we count the (rescaled) *commonness* of the option values. *e.g.* Option `CellLabelAutoDelete` has value `True` for *Message, Package, Text, Palette* and *ordinary Notebook*, but `False` for *Help* windows, so the *commonness* of `CellLabelAutoDelete` for *Message, Package, Text, Palette, ordinary Notebook* and *Help* will be `MapAt[Rescale, Tally[{True, True, True, True, True, False}]\[Transpose], 2]\[Transpose]`, which is `{{True, 1}, {False, 0}}`. *i.e.* the more common the value of an option is, the more the *commonness* of the option approaches 1. By counting the *commonness*, we can identify the most unique options a Notebook type has.

```
nboptSet = AbsoluteOptions /@ nblist;
nbopts = nboptSet // Flatten // #[[All, 1]] & // Union;
optdataRules = DeleteCases[
      {#, MapAt[Rescale, Tally[# /. nboptSet]\[Transpose], 2]\[Transpose]} & /@ nbopts,
      {_, {{__}}}, 1]\[Transpose] //
    MapAt[Map[Rule @@ # &, #, {2}] &, #, 2] & //
   SortBy[#, First] &;
```

At last we plot out the chart:

```
MapThread[#1 /. #2 &, {optdataRules[[1]] /. #, optdataRules[[2]]}] & /@ nboptSet //
    Map[Item["", Background -> GrayLevel[# + .8]] &, #, {2}] & //
   Prepend[#, optdataRules[[1]]] & //
  Prepend[#\[Transpose], {"", "Msg", "Pkg", "Txt", "Plt", "ONb", "Hlp"}] & //
 Grid[#, Frame -> All, Alignment -> Left, FrameStyle -> GrayLevel[.7]] &
```

[image: commonness statistics]

Now it's clear to see that `CellInsertionPointCell` is (one of) the perfect "fingerprint" of *ordinary Notebook*-s. So the filter function is simple:

```
Pick[#,
   (CellInsertionPointCell /. AbsoluteOptions[#, CellInsertionPointCell]) =!= None & /@ #
   ] & @ Notebooks[]
```

[image: ordnb filter result]

Comment: You've done what I was too lazy (*ashamed*) to do. Thank you :)

Comment: @Kuba You're welcome:) I think I spent too much time on trying different color schemes for the `Grid` O_o

Comment: It is standard for me that I'm wasting 80% time for secondary quests while playing with mma :)

Comment: @Kuba I'm hoping someone will give a [machine learning and classification](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/MachineLearning.html) answer :D

Comment: Oh my, there will be so many things to test. :)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know any neat answer but here's one that works for me at the moment.

- How we can detect **Help, Text, Package** type notebooks:

  ```
  "DocumentType" /. NotebookInformation /@ Notebooks[]
  ```

  > ```
  > {"Notebook", "Notebook", "Notebook", "Help", "Package", "Text", "Notebook",
  > "Notebook", "Notebook", "Notebook"}
  > ```
- **Message** is the only one with no external `"StyleDefinitions"`:

  ```
  {#, "StyleDefinitions" /. NotebookInformation[#]} & /@ Notebooks[]
  ```

  > [image]

  In fact this method could help further, but people often change things in styles so I do not trust it. Let's:
- ... find **Palettes** using `FrontEndTokens` ([list of tokens](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2572/5478)), with a support of  [answer on MathGroup](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2009/Jan/msg00091.html) by [John Fultz](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/309/john-fultz):

  ```
  FE`Evaluate[FEPrivate`GetPopupList["MenuListPaletteWindows"]]
  ```

So at the end I'm using:

```
Composition[
 Complement[#, FE`Evaluate[FEPrivate`GetPopupList["MenuListPaletteWindows"]][[;;,1]]] &,
 DeleteCases[#, {_, {"Text" | "Help" | "Package", _}} | {_, {_, None}}, 1][[;; , 1]] &,
 Map[{#, {"DocumentType", "StyleDefinitions"} /. NotebookInformation[#]} &, #] &
  ][Notebooks[]]
```

But it is soo ugly :(

Comment: +1. btw instead of `NotebookInformation`, it might be worth trying `AbsoluteOptions` on every nb, I believe the information will be more than enough to distinguish one from another.

Comment: @Silvia You are probably right, but there is to much to scan  :) so I've taken easier but longer road

Comment: The scan can be done automatically. (well at least they appear to be if we ignore all the coding time!) Please see my answer for detail :)

Answer (score 3):

Palettes have a specific window frame, so:

```
DeleteCases[Notebooks[], x_ /; MemberQ[Options[x], WindowFrame -> "Palette"]]
```

The Help seems to have a specific docked cell, so:

```
DeleteCases[Notebooks[], 
 x_ /; MemberQ[Options[x], DockedCells -> 
 FEPrivate`FrontEndResource["FEExpressions", "HelpViewerToolbar"]]]
```

So you can combine these two:

```
DeleteCases[Notebooks[], 
 x_ /; MemberQ[Options[x], 
   HoldPattern[_ -> 
     FEPrivate`FrontEndResource["FEExpressions", 
       "HelpViewerToolbar"] | "Palette"]]]
```

...and continuing along like this you should hopefully be able to find notebook options that are specific only to the sort of notebooks you want to exclude, and once identified use that as a way of excluding the notebook.

Answer (score 2):

```
Names["FrontEnd`*" ~~ "`" ... ~~ "Notebook"] // Column
```

gives

```
FrontEnd`ButtonNotebook
FrontEnd`ClipboardNotebook
FrontEnd`DebuggerStackNotebook
FrontEnd`EvaluationNotebook
FrontEnd`HelpBrowserNotebook
FrontEnd`InputNotebook
FrontEnd`MessagesNotebook
FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook
FrontEnd`SetSelectedNotebook
```

Of these, the following seem useful for filtering

```
useful = {(*FrontEnd`ClipboardNotebook,*)
  FrontEnd`DebuggerStackNotebook, FrontEnd`HelpBrowserNotebook, 
  FrontEnd`MessagesNotebook}
```

I have commented out `ClipboardNotebook`, as I do not know how it works. But probably it is useful. I thought `HelpBrowserNotebook` was not useful at first, but it is just something different than I expected. To generate a `HelpBrowserNotebook`, evaluate

```
FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`HelpBrowserLookup["hello"]]
```

Then, a first filter, that you could combine with other answers, would be

```
Complement[Notebooks[], 
 Cases[FrontEndExecute[#[]] & /@ useful, _NotebookObject]]
```

Comment: I will take a look at it later :) I was wondering what were you looking for in tokens thresd :P

Comment: @Kuba haha, well actually I wasn't looking for this, I just stumbled upon it :P. It all started with me finally modifying KeyEventTranslations.tr (I'm such a noob :( :p ) and finding some new tokens.

Comment: Some useful information about legacy help browser: "[How to invoke and use legacy Help Browser in new versions of Mathematica?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5780065/590388)", "[Making a working copy of the legacy documentation for version 5 inside new versions of Mathematica](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6894351/590388)."