# Keyboard shortcut for moving to last edit location/cell

Tags: front-end, notebooks

When you have long notebook with hundreds of cells, you sometimes need to scroll/jump manually to your last edited cell. I dind't find any shortcut for doing that. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think there is any. But maybe you can construct one by scanning the `CellChangeTimes` of all the cells and picking out the latest one.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is any shortcut for that. But we can always construct one by scanning the `CellChangeTimes` of all the cells and picking out the latest one.

Here is a quick solution:

```
Button[
       "Find me\nthe last edit!",
        {#, CurrentValue[#, CellChangeTimes]} & /@ 
           Cells[SelectedNotebook[], CellStyle -> {"Input"}] //
          DeleteCases[#, {CellObject[_], {}}] & //
         # /. {co_CellObject, timestamp_List} :> {co, Flatten[timestamp][[-1]]} & //
        SortBy[#, Last][[-1, 1]] & //
       SelectionMove[#, All, Cell] &
      ]
```

Select the generated button, and from the menu bar, select **Palettes** -> **Generate Palette from Selection**:

[image: generate the palette]

It should find the last edited `"Input"`-style cell in the current selected notebook.

**Note:** In order to use this solution, the *notebook history tracking* option should be enabled:

[image: enable the notebook history tracking]

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I get an `Part::partw: "Part -1 of {} does not exist"` error message. This may be due to the fact that CellChangeTimes sometimes contains a list with a list of values and sometimes a list with a single value.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I noticed that, too. But I've `Flatten`ed the list before doing the `Part` :( I'm investigating.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries It seems some Cells doesn't include a `CellChangeTimes` option or thay're empty as Kuba said. Will fix it soon.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Kuba Have fixed the code. Cells without `CellChangeTimes` have been abandoned before `Sort`ing.

Comment: @Silvia Since you are around, please take a look, maybe you have something new to say: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44588/5478