# How to open all notebooks in "Open Recent"?

Tags: menu

Consider the notebooks in the Menubar list "Open Recent":

[image]

#### question:

How to **programmatically** open all of them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of Recently Opened Files](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87838/list-of-recently-opened-files) Then map [`NotebookOpen`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookOpen.html) over the list.

Comment: @Doman, Yes it does, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

This works on macOS.

```
SystemOpen /@ (FileNameJoin[{$RootDirectory}~Join~(Append @@ ((First@Last[#])[[;; 2]]))[[2 ;;]]] & /@   Lookup[Options@$FrontEnd, NotebooksMenu])
```