# No-op front-end token to "unmap" key events

Tags: front-end, keyboard, linux

Is there a [no-op](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP_(code)) [front-end token](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2572/what-is-the-complete-list-of-valid-front-end-tokens) that does nothing?  The reason I ask this is because on Linux, Mathematica 13.3 produces nonsensical characters (see image below) on pressing `Ctrl-g`, `Ctrl-h`, etc., and I would like to "unmap" these key events.

[image]

I figured out a way to accomplish this by adding the following key event in `KeyEventsTranslations.tr`:

```
Item[KeyEvent["g", Modifiers->{Control}], "MacintoshOpenDeskAccessory"],
```

"MacintoshOpenDeskAccessory" seems to be a macOS front-end token that has no function on Linux, so `Ctrl-g` gets ignored.  But this feels like a kludge and I was wondering if there is a proper no-op front-end token.

Comment: Why don't  you simply delete the problematic key events from the file?

Comment: @azerbajdzan There are no key-event definitions for the offending key events.  I guess they are hard-coded in the source.

Comment: So then the key shortcuts might be caused by your operating system and not Mathematica. What happens when you press `CTRL+G` in some other software that is native to your operating system?

Comment: @azerbajdzan I doubt that.  I use Debian + i3 and all my global desktop shortcuts are the ones I've set by hand, and Ctrl-g isn't something I've set.  Mathematica on Linux is clunky, and unfortunately Wolfram doesn't seem to care. But `Ctrl-g` may not be a hard-coded key event though -- perhaps some special character input that doesn't seem to work properly.

Comment: Open some native text editor and press `ctrl+g`. What happens?

Comment: @azerbajdzan Nothing.