# How do I find the value of specific printing options?

Tags: options

I'd like to programmatically save (and then temporarily change and restore) specific printing options. I get as far as

```
Options[Notebook, PrintingOptions]
```

but don't know what to do next to extract specific options, for example `PrintingMargins`, from the (long) resulting list.

Comment: Doesn't `"PrintingMargins" /. (PrintingOptions /. Options[Notebook, PrintingOptions])` work for you?

Comment: @J.M.: That works. There's no API for extracting nested options?

Comment: API, nothing. What would be the trouble with using `ReplaceAll` anyway?

Comment: @J.M.: No problem, I just expected something more compact and targeted to options.

Comment: You kids today don't know how good you've got it! When I were a lad, `ReplaceAll` was all we had for option handling! We'd make six nested replacements to process our options, with `Hold` and `Release` for evaluation control, and `Block` our only scoping construct. And we were thankful!

Comment: It can't be this: `OptionValue[
 OptionValue[Options[Notebook, PrintingOptions], 
  "PrintingOptions"], "PrintingMargins"]`. Maybe `ReplaceAll` is better after all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 CurrentValue[Notebook, {PrintingOptions, "PrintingMargins"}]
 (* {{54, 54}, {72, 72}} *)
```

You can also use `$FrontEnd` ,  `EvaluationNotebook[]` ... as the first argument.

Other examples:

```
 CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, EvaluatorNames]
 (* {"Local" -> {"AutoStartOnLaunch" -> True}} *)
 CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {EvaluatorNames, "Local"}]
 (* {"AutoStartOnLaunch" -> True} *)
 CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {EvaluatorNames, "Local", "AutoStartOnLaunch"}]
 (* True *)
```

Update: See also this Q/A: [Items known by `CurrentValue`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1379/125).