# The value of an option inside a native function

Tags: plotting, programming, options

I'm looking for something similar to `AbsoluteOptions` but that can be evaluated inside the function. That is, I want to read the absolute settings of options specified in the current context. For example, instead of:

```
AbsoluteOptions[
 Plot[
  Sin[x]
  , {x, 0, 2 Pi}
  , PlotRange -> Automatic
  ]
 , PlotRange]
```

> {PlotRange -> {{0., 6.28319}, {-1., 1.}}}

I would like to have something like

```
Plot[
 Sin[x]
 , {x, 0, 2 Pi}
 , PlotRange -> Automatic
 , Epilog -> Inset[
   "PlotRange is " <> ToString@AbsoluteOptions[PlotRange]
   , {4, 1}]
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

is it possible to read the absolute settings for options associated with the current function environment?

Comment: Are you interested primarily in `PlotRange`, which is [known to be difficult to get](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18034/how-to-get-the-real-plotrange-using-absoluteoptions)?

Comment: @Michael_E2 Yes, my current need is to have access to `PlotRange`, but the question seems interesting to me in general.

Comment: Why not `Show[{#},Epilog->Inset[ToString@AbsoluteOptions[#,PlotRange],{4,1}]]&@Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,2 Pi},PlotRange->Automatic]`

Comment: Even if possible, you may [bite your tail](http://xkcd.com/688/). Just imagine appending an `Imagesize` to the Plot Label, which in turns increase the image size

Comment: The suggestion by @Karsten_7 its interesting, but that's not strictly speaking inside the function. The problem is way more complicated I expected, among other things `PlotRange`  for other plots such as `ContourPlot` returns only 2 parameters, when 3 are expected.

Comment: I don't know of any way to do this but on the slim chance a method exists it is probably through [`CurrentValue`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1379/121).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `DisplayFunction` for this:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 DisplayFunction :> (Show[#, 
     Epilog -> 
      Inset["PlotRange is " <> ToString@PlotRange[#], {4, 1}]] &)]
```

Instead of buggy `PlotRange` and `AbsoluteOptions` you can use much more reliable `plotRange` function from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18040/280):

```
plotRange[plot : (_Graphics | _Graphics3D | _Graph)] := 
 Reap[NotebookDelete[
    First@{PrintTemporary[
       Show[plot, Axes -> True, Frame -> False, 
        Ticks -> ((Sow[{##}]; Automatic) &), 
        DisplayFunction -> Identity, PlotRangePadding -> None, 
        ImageSize -> 0]], FinishDynamic[]}]][[2, 1]]

Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 DisplayFunction :> (Show[#, 
     Epilog -> 
      Inset["PlotRange is " <> ToString@plotRange[#], {4, 1}]] &)]
```

[image: plot]

Speaking about `ContourPlot`, there is no way to extract the plot range for Z-direction because produced 2D `Graphics` object does not contain this information. But you can catch the call to `Contours` using the technique used in the `plotRange` function:

```
{pl, plRange} = 
  Reap[ContourPlot[x^2 - y^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
    Contours -> ((Sow[{##}]; {-1, 0, 1}) &)]];
plRange
```

> {{{-4., 4., 10}}}

I do not know what the third number means but the first two correspond to the actual plot range in Z-direction as can be seen from `Plot3D`:

```
plotRange[Plot3D[x^2 - y^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]]
```

> {{-2., 2.}, {-2., 2.}, {-4., 4.}}

Comment: I believe I haven't used `DisplayFunction` since version 5.2.  +1 for old-school! :-)

Answer (score 7):

Not sure how robust it is, but the following seems to work for `PlotRange`:

```
ClearAll[plt];
plt = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 3 Pi}, PlotRange -> Automatic, 
           PlotLabel -> Dynamic@("PlotRange is " <> ToString@PlotRange[plt])]
```

and

```
ClearAll[plt1];
plt1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 3 Pi}, PlotRange -> Automatic, 
          PlotLabel ->  Dynamic@("PlotRange is " <> 
                           ToString@(PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[plt1, PlotRange]))]
```

both give

[image]

Similarly,

```
ClearAll[plt2];
plt2 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> Automatic,
      Epilog -> Dynamic@Inset[
               Style["PlotRange is " <> ToString@PlotRange[plt2], 14], {4, 1}]]
```

and

```
 ClearAll[plt3];
 plt3 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> Automatic,
    Epilog -> Dynamic@Inset[
     Style["PlotRange is " <> ToString@(PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[plt3, PlotRange]),
             14], {4, 1}]]
```

both give

[image]

Comment: This one is really creative!:)