# What are all the returns from FrontEnd`NeedCurrentFrontEndSymbolsPacket

Tags: front-end, options, undocumented

So Mr. Wizard points out [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13451/what-is-the-complete-list-of-valid-frontend-packet-types/13452#13452) that we can get all the FE packets via `` FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`NeedCurrentFrontEndSymbolsPacket[]][[1,1,4]] ``

I was wondering what all the other element are. I think I've managed to pin a number of them down: (Ignore the `` MyTools` `` context. It's just the context I give to my tools application.)

```
{
   {
    {MyTools`$FESettings, MyTools`$SeeminglyRandom, 
     MyTools`$FEDataForms, MyTools`$FEPacketList},
    {MyTools`$FEBoxForms, MyTools`$FEInterfaceStuff}
    },
   MyTools`$FEData
   } = FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`NeedCurrentFrontEndSymbolsPacket[];
```

The thing is, the only ones of those assignments that I'm actually confident are, (obviously) the packets, the data forms, and the box forms. In particular, the `<FE Call>[[1,1,2]]` element is very confusing.

For those just scanning it looks like:

```
"Graphics",
"NotebookDefault",
"Clip",
"Infinity",
"None",
"Notebook",
"Vertical",
"Bottom",
"RGBColor",
"Null",
"Generic",
"BeforeCell",
"Before",
"GlobalPreferences",
"Baseline",
"Left",
"Axis",
"GrayLevel",
"Placeholder",
"Queued",
"ToggleFalse",
"Closed",
"Toggle",
"Full",
"ForwardBackward",
"Preemptive",
"Tiny",
"Forward",
"Backward",
"Open",
"CellGroup",
"Expression",
"GeneratedCell",
"Version2",
"Version1",
"True",
"All",
"AutomaticPreview",
"False",
"After",
"AfterCell",
"ButtonContents",
"Top",
"Manual",
"AutomaticCenterLeftCenterRight",
"Style",
"Fixed",
"AutomaticLeftCenterRight",
"Empty",
"Short",
"Fit",
"FitAll",
"Automatic",
"SoundAndGraphics",
"AlignmentMarker",
"Sound",
"FullWithinScreen",
"Center",
"GroupTogetherNestedGrouping",
"Selection",
"WindowWidth",
"PaperWidth",
"Inherited",
"GroupTogetherGrouping",
"GraphicsGrouping",
"Cell",
"Small",
"OutputGrouping",
"InputGrouping",
"Round",
"Scaled",
"CellContents",
"DialogBox",
"SectionGrouping",
"Scrollbars",
"TitleGrouping",
"Previous",
"Scrollable",
"EvaluationCell",
"Next",
"ShrinkToFit",
"Long",
"NormalGrouping",
"VisibleCell",
"Ceiling",
"Rotate",
"ResizeToFit",
"Floor",
"Expand",
"ButtonCell",
"ButtonData",
"LineWrapParts",
"Medium",
"Wipe",
"Sizing",
"TextParagraph",
"Ex",
"Push",
"Above",
"$SystemCharacterEncoding",
"TextLine",
"CrossFade",
"GlobalSession",
"Fade",
"Notification",
"GraphicsContents",
"Word",
"Locking",
"Horizontal",
"Character",
"Right",
"SelectionCellDefaultStyle",
"Large",
"Language",
"SelectionCellParentStyle",
"SelectionCell",
"RightClickTarget"
```

Whereas, say, the stuff I pegged as interface stuff (I guess this is all interface stuff, by I was thinking more like the notebooks/front ends/menus stuff) is:

```
"Notebook",
"Cell",
"CellGroup",
"CellGroupData",
"CellTags",
"CellLabel",
"FrontEndVersion",
"AutoScroll",
"CellObject",
"Interactive",
"InsertionPointObject",
"Above",
"Below",
"ParentList",
"FrontEndObject",
"NotebookObject",
"WindowTitle",
"FontReencoding",
"Interlaced",
"TransparentColor",
"SpanningCharacters",
"Box",
"Baseline",
"CellBoundingBox",
"CellElementsBoundingBox",
"ContentsBoundingBox",
"ShrinkWrapBoundingBox",
"GeneratedCell",
"Selection",
"IgnoreCase",
"NotebookSelection",
"AnimationDirection",
"Forward",
"Backward",
"ForwardBackward",
"CellStyle",
"Open",
"Closed",
"EvaluationCell",
"RawData",
"StyleDefinitions",
"$FrontEnd",
"$FrontEndSession",
"$DefaultFrontEnd",
"Hue",
"CMYKColor",
"Item",
"Menu",
"MenuEvaluator",
"MacintoshFileTypes",
"FunctionTemplate"
```