# How to cap ImageSize at the notebook width?

Tags: graphics, front-end, dynamic, printing, scaling

`Graphics[{Circle[]}, ImageSize -> Automatic]` creates a figure which is 360 pixels wide (same as `Medium`), if it fits in the notebook window. Otherwise, its size is reduced to fit.

Is it possible to have a size specification which is similarly capped at the notebook width, but has a default size different from 360 pixels?

`Graphics[{Circle[]}, ImageSize -> UpTo[500]]` does not do this.

The use case is having a large figure on screen, but making sure it fits on the page when printing.

---

Is it possible to get it done without `Dynamic`?  If not, what is the best way with `Dynamic`?  The following uses the window width instead of the actual available space:

```
Graphics[Circle[], 
 ImageSize -> Dynamic@Min[500, First@CurrentValue[WindowSize]]]
```

---

I am looking for solutions which work just like `ImageSize -> Automatic`, except that the default size is something else than 360 pixels.  I strongly prefer solutions that do not require a running kernel.

Comment: ImageResize[Graphics[{Circle[]}], 500]

Comment: @Jenny_mathy That will first rasterize the figure, then resize it with low quality.  If we want to rasterize, it would be better to use `Rasterize[fig, ImageSize -> 500]`.  But I do not want to rasterize it.

Comment: I take it that `Full` is too big? "When the cell is printed, ImageSize->Full corresponds to the full width of the content area of the page."

Comment: @Alan Yes. It may cause the bottom of the figure to be cut off. Even if it doesn't, after a certain point further magnification is not a benefit. I would rather see several small plots above each other than a single huge one.  However, 360 pixels is a bit too small for my current application. It causes labels in a BarChart to overlap (even after 90 deg rotation).

Comment: There is not serious problem of course. But if there is a way to do this, it would be nice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure it is what you want, but have you tried

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], "GraphicsBoxOptionsImageSizeRaw"] = 500
```

This instantly resizes all graphics inside a notebook to 500 pixels as long as your notebook window is large enough.

As @Kuba pointed out, this can be used as option for `Graphics`

```
Graphics[{Circle[]}, 
  ImageSize -> Automatic, 
  BaseStyle -> "GraphicsBoxOptionsImageSizeRaw" -> 200]
```

Another possibility due to @CarlWoll is

```
Graphics[Circle[], ImageSizeRaw -> {500}]
```

### How I found it

Initially, I was sure I had seen an option for that so I looked through

```
AbsoluteOptions[$Notebooks]
```

It turned out that what I had in mind was the option `"DefaultNewGraphics"` which is something else. My next thought was that it is very likely that this is exposed through `CurrentValue`. We have a question [about all possible current values](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1379/187) which led me, only the devil knows how, to [this pastebin](https://pastebin.com/H3bKtXkW). A quick scan revealed the `"GraphicsBoxOptionsImageSizeRaw"` setting.

Comment: Almost. I wonder if this is settable at the level of `Graphics`.  It seems to be settable in `BoxData` as `GraphicsBoxOptions->{ImageSizeRaw->130}`.  This is definitely useful in practice, though not exactly what I asked in the question.

Comment: Well, @Kuba just gave the answer.  Can you include that in the answer?  And who shall I give the bounty to now? :)

Comment: @Szabolcs Already on it.

Comment: An alternate version is: `Graphics[Circle[], 
 BaseStyle -> {GraphicsBoxOptions -> {ImageSizeRaw -> {700}}}]`. Notice the use of {700} instead of 700.

Comment: Or even `Graphics[Circle[], ImageSizeRaw->{500}]`

Answer (score 5):

This is not a general solution but an improvement for `Dynamic` approach. It will run completely FrontEnd side:

```
Graphics[Circle[]
  , ImageSize -> Dynamic @ If[
        FEPrivate`Less[CurrentValue[{WindowSize, 1}] - 100, 500]
      , Full
      , 500
      , 500
    ]
]
```

`-100` is unfortuantely manual, will try to get margins+toolbars width somehow.

Comment: Looks like you need `First@CurrentValue["DocumentAndWindowSize"]`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov looks like this + CellMargins should be enough. Having trouble combining them though :/